# Python - Why can't I use generators inside the print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

my code:

```
a=[3,3,3,3,3,3,45,4,5,2,2,4,3,3,3,3]
print(x for x in set(a))
```

output:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb62dccec>
```

why? And how can I print the `set` using one line?

Comment: print `set(a)`? or wrap it in a list like `print ([x for x in set(a)])`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a generator. Just print the set as is:

```
print(set(a))
```

If you want to do something with each item use

```
print(*(something(x) for x in set(a)), sep=', ')  # unpacks generator, bare
```

or even

```
print({something(x) for x in set(a)})  # creates new set, surrounded by {}
```

or

```
print([something(x) for x in set(a)])  # creates new list, surrounded by []
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually wanted the second line, to print it with commas, using seperator, and not `.join`.

Comment: Use `print(*set(a), sep=", ") ` then.

Answer (score 2):

You can `print` it like this:

```
print(set(a))
```

The reason your current code doesn't work is because the `print` function doesn't consume generator objects.

Answer (score 2):

printing just prints the object (which is a generator), it does not consume its data.
You could convert it to a list and thus print its values:

```
a = [3,3,3,3,3,3,45,4,5,2,2,4,3,3,3,3]
print([x for x in set(a)])
# here^-----------------^
```